# Extracting a list of strings that match a pattern for the beginning of each string

Tags: c#

I have a pretty long string from which I want to extract strings that match a pattern for the beginning of each string. For example, suppose I have this:

```
string TheLongString = Lorem ipsum "SomeWordOne" dolor sit "SomeWordTwo" amet;
```

How do I extract from this string all the strings that are in quotes and that start with SomeWord? For instance, in this case, the list should contain `"SomeWordOne"` and `"SomeWordTwo"`.

Comment: You can have a look at regular expressions (http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match). By the way, the whole string needs to be in double quotes and the double quotes need to be properly escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the pattern you are searching for was not a single word ([kd.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22540052/2175939) will work for that), you could use a Regex match to do what you want:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"SomeWord[^\"]*\"");
var matches = regex.Matches(TheLongString);
List<string> myMatchedStrings = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    myMatchedStrings.Add(match.Value);
}
```

If you don't want the double quotes included in your results, use the following drop-in replacement which uses [Regex Look Behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find your opening quote, but it won't actually show up in the result:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=\")SomeWord[^\"]*");
```

Or even if you wanted to exclude "SomeWord" from your result:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=\"SomeWord)[^\"]*");
```

That should leave `myMatchedStrings` with a list of your pattern, as long as the pattern starts and ends with double quotes and starts with "SomeWord", but you can adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** You need to `split` the string based on `Space` delimeter using `string.Split()` method.

**Step 2:** iterate over all of the words and identify if any word starts with string `"SomeWord` using `string.StartsWith()` method. if it is there then add it into the `List`

Try This:

```
string str="string TheLongString = Lorem ipsum \"SomeWordOne\" 
                            dolor sit \"SomeWordTwo\" amet;";

var words = str.Split(new []{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<string> selectedWords = new List<string>();
foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (word.StartsWith("\"SomeWord"))
        selectedWords.Add(word);
}
```

**EDIT:** as pointed in comments if your `someword` contain spaces then the above method does not fit.

Comment: @Selman22: yes thats a good point,thanks let me edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can either use `IndexOf` (using the overload with `startIndex` parameter) and `Substring` repeatedly, or you can use a regular expression.

In the `IndexOf` case, you'd simply search for `"SomeWord`, then find a closing quote, substring that and repeat.

The regular expression would look something like this:

```
\"(?<Inside>SomeWord[^\"]*)\"
```

Answer (score 0):

var matches = TheLongString.Split(' ').Where(p => p.StartsWith("SomeWord"));

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a custom Split function. @Sudhakar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22540005/3010968) should work if your SomeWords doesn't contain any space(s). But if it does than you can use an extension method like this:

```
public static string[] SplitBy(this string source,char separator)
{
    var chars = source.ToCharArray();
    var temp = new List<char>();
    var words = new List<string>();
    bool splitControl = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] == separator && !splitControl)
        {
           splitControl = true;
           continue;
        }
        else if (chars[i] == separator && splitControl)
        {
           words.Add(new string(temp.ToArray()));
           temp.Clear();
           splitControl = false;
           continue;
        }

        if(splitControl) temp.Add(chars[i]);

    }

    if(temp.Any()) words.Add(new string(temp.ToArray()));
    return words.ToArray();
}
```

This function return all the words that are wrapped by double-quotes.For example:

```
string TheLongString = "Lorem ipsum \"SomeWordOne\" dolor sit \"SomeWordTwo\" amet";
var result = TheLongString.SplitBy('"');
```

This will return `SomeWordOne` and `SomeWordTwo`.If you want to filter the returning result you can simply use `LINQ`:

```
var result = TheLongString.SplitBy('"').Where(x => x.StartsWith("SomeWord"));
```